# How to optimize update_post_meta?

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I have written the code with many update_post_meta entries:

```
update_post_meta($order_id, '_shipping_first_name', $order->get_billing_first_name() );
update_post_meta($order_id, '_shipping_last_name', $order->get_billing_last_name() );
update_post_meta($order_id, '_shipping_company', $order->get_billing_company() );
update_post_meta($order_id, '_shipping_address_1', $order->get_billing_address_1() );
update_post_meta($order_id, '_shipping_address_2', $order->get_billing_address_2() );
update_post_meta($order_id, '_shipping_postcode', $order->get_billing_postcode() );
update_post_meta($order_id, '_shipping_city', $order->get_billing_city() );
update_post_meta($order_id, '_shipping_state', $order->get_billing_state() );
update_post_meta($order_id, '_shipping_country', $order->get_billing_country() );
```

For DRY principle I tried to use an array with for loops, but it doesn't work:

```
$data = array(
    array( '_shipping_first_name', $order->get_billing_first_name() ),
    array( '_shipping_last_name', $order->get_billing_last_name() ),
    array( '_shipping_company', $order->get_billing_company() ),
    array( '_shipping_address_1', $order->get_billing_address_1() ),
    array( '_shipping_address_2', $order->get_billing_address_2() ),
    array( '_shipping_postcode', $order->get_billing_postcode() ),
    array( '_shipping_city', $order->get_billing_city() ),
    array( '_shipping_state', $order->get_billing_state() ),
    array( '_shipping_country', $order->get_billing_country() )
);

for ( $row = 0; $row < 9; $row++) {
    for ( $col = 0; $col < 2; $col++) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, [$row], [$col] );
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using 2 for loops, wouldn't it be easier to use `'key' => $order->...`? Then a `foreach ( $data as $key => $value )`? `[$row]` will just be a new array containing a number from the `for` loop. Arrays in PHP can have named indexes and act as dictionaries, numbered indices are unusual and rarely needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want you're better creating an associative array and then walking over it with a `foreach` loop as shown below :

```php
$data = array(
    '_shipping_first_name' => $order->get_billing_first_name(), 
    '_shipping_last_name' => $order->get_billing_last_name(), 
    '_shipping_company' => $order->get_billing_company(), 
    '_shipping_address_1' => $order->get_billing_address_1(), 
    '_shipping_address_2' => $order->get_billing_address_2(), 
    '_shipping_postcode' => $order->get_billing_postcode(), 
    '_shipping_city' => $order->get_billing_city(), 
    '_shipping_state' => $order->get_billing_state(), 
    '_shipping_country' => $order->get_billing_country()
);

foreach ( $data as $meta_key => $meta_value ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, $meta_key, $meta_value );
}
```